# How to export inner function from (exported default) outer const block?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have this code in file "Strings.js":

```
const Strings = {
    getString(str) {
        ... // some logic
    },
    ... // more functions
}

export default Strings;
```

I want to import both the whole thing (Strings) and/or just the getString function from another file like that:

`import Strings, { getString }  from '../../utils/Strings';`

or maybe just:

`import { getString }  from '../../utils/Strings';`

to be able to write simply getString and not Strings.getString (in multiple lines).

When I try to use it, I get the following error:

`Attempted import error: 'getString' is not exported from '../../utils/Strings'.`

Sorry if this question was already asked, I could not find an answer.

Comment: if you want the function separate from the object why not just define and export it separately?

Comment: @Craicerjack I can do it, I just wanted to know if there is a way to export it from within the object.

Comment: Do you also need `Strings` as context. e.g. using calling other methods using `this.someMethod()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use named exports, not an object:

```
export function getString(str) {
    … // some logic
}
… // more functions
```

You can then import them as a namespace object

```
import * as Strings from '../../utils/Strings';

… Strings.getString(…) …
```

or directly

```
import { getString }  from '../../utils/Strings';

… getString(…) …
```

If you absolutely want/need to write `import Strings from '…';` (you really shouldn't), you will need to add a default export object:

```
… // function declarations

export default { getString }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to

```
function getString (str) {
}
const Strings = {
    getString
}
export default Strings
export { getString }
```

or

```
const Strings = {
  getStrings(str) {
  }
}

const { getStrings } = String

export default Strings
export { getString }
```

So, there is no direct way to export an object property